# Flutter: insert textfield data into the MYSQL database using POST method in php

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart

I try to insert my text field data into the MYSQL database using PHP post method.
Here This is My code for SAVE data.

POST method Showing this **Undefined index: visitor_name in**

database connected successfully
GET data works Properly
getting data in List View there is no problem in getdata function But save data Funtion Not Working

```
class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Homepage> createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextEditingController txtVname = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController txtVnumber = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController txtvemail = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController txtvReason = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController txtename = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController txtRole = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController txtemail = TextEditingController();

    bool _valvname = false;
    bool _valvnumber = false;
    bool _valvemail = false;
    bool _valvReason = false;
    bool _valename = false;
    bool _valRole = false;
    bool _valemail = false;

    bool visible = false;

    Future insertData() async {
      setState(() {
        visible = true;
      });

      String visitor_name = txtVname.text;
      String visitor_num = txtVnumber.text;
      String visitor_email = txtemail.text;
      String visitor_Reason = txtvReason.text;
      String emp_name = txtename.text;
      String emp_Role = txtRole.text;
      String emp_email = txtemail.text;

      var Data = {
        'visitor_name': visitor_name,
        'visitor_num': visitor_num,
        'visitor_email': visitor_email,
        'visitor_Reason': visitor_Reason,
        'emp_name': emp_name,
        'emp_Role': emp_Role,
        'emp_email': emp_email,
      };
      var url = "https://astatic-scab.000webhostapp.com/vsave.php";
      var res = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: jsonEncode(Data));
      var message = jsonDecode(res.body);
      if (message == "true") {
        print("Successful " + message);
      } else {
        print("Error: " + message);
      }
    }
```

AND MY PHP CODE

```
<?php
include "config.php";
$visitor_name=$_POST['visitor_name'];
$visitor_num=$_POST['visitor_num'];
$visitor_email=$_POST['visitor_email'];
$visitor_Reason=$_POST['visitor_Reason'];
$emp_name=$_POST['emp_name'];
$emp_Role=$_POST['emp_Role'];
$emp_email=$_POST['emp_email'];


if($visitor_name!="" && $visitor_num!="" && $visitor_email!="" && $visitor_Reason!="" && $emp_name!="" && $emp_Role!="" && $emp_email!="" ){
$sql="insert into Enquiry (visitor_name,visitor_num,visitor_email,visitor_Reason,emp_name,emp_Role,emp_email) values('$visitor_name','$visitor_num','$visitor_email','$visitor_Reason','$emp_name','$emp_Role',$emp_email');";
if ($con->query($sql)){
echo "true";
}else{
echo "false";
}
}
?>
```

AND THIS SOME MY TEXTFIELD CODE I DID THIS FOR ALL THE TEXT INPUTS
visitor_name,visitor_num,visitor_email,visitor_Reason,emp_name,emp_email,emp_role,

```
children: [
                                TextField(
                                  controller: txtVname,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      errorText: _valvname
                                          ? 'Please fill the detail'
                                          : null,
                                      labelText: "Visitors Name",
                                      labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Color(0xff6D6C6CFF))),
                                ),
                                TextField(
                                  controller: txtVnumber,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: "Visitors Mobile Number",
                                    labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                                        color: const Color(0xff6D6C6CFF)),
                                    errorText:
                                        _valvnumber ? 'Can\'t be Empty' : null,
                                  ),
                                ),
```

[THIS IS MY TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxgcx.png)

AND THE ERROR MESSAGES ARE
when I click submit button this is the error message is showing
I don't know where to look for the bugs.

```
E/flutter (13778): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter (13778): <br />
E/flutter (13778): ^
E/flutter (13778): 
E/flutter (13778): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1405:5)
E/flutter (13778): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1272:9)
E/flutter (13778): #2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:937:22)
E/flutter (13778): #3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:40:10)
E/flutter (13778): #4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)
E/flutter (13778): #5      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:216:41)
E/flutter (13778): #6      jsonDecode (dart:convert/json.dart:155:10)
E/flutter (13778): #7      _HomepageState.build.insertData (package:vms_1/Home_Page.dart:67:21)
E/flutter (13778): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13778):
```

AND THIS IS WHAT PHP SHOWS

```
Notice: Undefined index: visitor_name in /storage/ssd4/645/18700645/public_html/vsave.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: visitor_num in /storage/ssd4/645/18700645/public_html/vsave.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: visitor_email in /storage/ssd4/645/18700645/public_html/vsave.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: visitor_Reason in /storage/ssd4/645/18700645/public_html/vsave.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: emp_name in /storage/ssd4/645/18700645/public_html/vsave.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: emp_Role in /storage/ssd4/645/18700645/public_html/vsave.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: emp_email in /storage/ssd4/645/18700645/public_html/vsave.php on line 9
```

and this too

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 8071): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
I/AssistStructure( 8071): Flattened final assist data: 388 bytes, containing 1 windows, 3 views
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 8071): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 8071): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: Most probably this is an issue with your Form not posting the data correctly. First check the FORM is of method POST and then check the which form fields are posted by checking something like this var_dump($_POST) in your php page.

Comment: How about you try not to jsonEncode your data and pass it like this body: Data but just make sure that on each value you add it like this "visitor_name": visitor_name.toString().

Comment: @KeiCredo @almaruf I think this the reason for not posting data correctly `W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 2726): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
I/AssistStructure( 2726): Flattened final assist data: 384 bytes, containing 1 windows, 3 views
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 2726): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 2726): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
`  when i type in textfleid i show this in debug mode. How to i sort it out.

Comment: @KeiCredo   **NOW ITS SHOWING LIKE THIS**  `E/flutter (17894): #0      _HomepageState.build.insertData (package:vms_1/Home_Page.dart:65:27)
E/flutter (17894): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17894): `

Answer (score 0):

Let's fix first your problem with your API. Please try to format your `insertData()` function similar to this:

```
Future insertData() async {
  setState(() {
    visible = true;
  });
  
  var url = "https://astatic-scab.000webhostapp.com/vsave.php";
  var response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(url),
    body: {
      "visitor_name": txtVname.text.toString(),
      "visitor_num": txtVnumber.text.toString(),
      "visitor_email": txtemail.text.toString(),
      "visitor_Reason": txtvReason.text.toString(),
      "emp_name": txtename.text.toString(),
      "emp_Role": txtRole.text.toString(),
      "emp_email": txtemail.text.toString(),
    },
  );
  var message = jsonDecode(res.body);
  if (message == "true") {
    print("Successful " + message);
  } else {
    print("Error: " + message);
  }
}
```

Comment: **NOW ITS SHOWING LIKE THIS**    `E/flutter (17894): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter (17894): #0      _HomepageState.build.insertData (package:vms_1/Home_Page.dart:65:27)
E/flutter (17894): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17894): `

Comment: you can try message == true in the if condition... because i just followed your code above..